# JAVA Accessibility support by Excelsior Jet

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, java-access-bridge

I have a application which supports screen readers via the Java Access Bridge. The jre version works fine with screen readers such as NVDA. We’ve have compiled our app with **Excelsior Jet** and found that everything works fine except for screen reading.

But another screen reader such as JAWS works fine.

Java version used is 1.7.72
NVDA used is 2014.2.

Comment: "everything works fine except for screen reading." - so what happens instead?  Error messages, any log files, description of what it does do may help diagnose the problem

Comment: Well the problem is that nothing happens. The swing components, none of them, are read by NVDA. Where as JAWS(another TTS reader) still reads the text on swing components.

Comment: On navigation through TAB the normal behavior is that the text on swing components is read bu the TTS software. It worked fine for application compiled normally in JAVA. But it is not working now since the application has been compiled using Excelsior-JET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with JAB specific to versions of Java SE 7 prior to 1.7.0_76. Excelsior JET 10.5 supports Java SE 7u76 since [Maintenance Pack 1](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/updates/10.5/mp1).

You can run your app on the Oracle JRE with `-Xcheck:jni` to check if hits that problem.

(In general, emailing our support works better than waiting until one of us does a search for "Excelsior" on Stack Overflow.)